# LuaJIT FFI : Segmentation fault when program terminates

Tags: c, lua, ffi, luajit

I am trying a very simple thing with LuaJIT ffi. Trying to open file in C code and then closing the file.

Following is the C Code fileWrite.c

```
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

FILE * createFile(char *fname){
    strcat(fname,".bin");
    FILE *file = fopen(fname, "wb");
    return file;
}

void close(FILE *fp){
    int status = fclose(fp);
}
```

And ffi call in lua as follows

```
local ffi = require("ffi") 
local so_file_path_name = "./fileWrite.so" --path for .so file
local qCLib  = ffi.load(so_file_path_name) 

local binfilepath = "./"

ffi.cdef[[
  void *malloc(size_t size);
  void free(void *ptr);

  typedef struct FILE FILE;  
  FILE* createFile(char *fname);
  void close(FILE *fp);
  ]]

function create(fileName) 
  filepath = binfilepath..fileName
  local filePathArg = ffi.new("char [?]", #filepath, filepath)
  local fp = qCLib["createFile"](filePathArg);
  return fp;
end

function close(fp) 
    qCLib["close"](fp)
    fp = nil
end

file = create("test")
print(file)
close(file)
print("after closing")
```

But when I run the code, I am getting segmentation fault error :

```
$ luajit test.lua 
cdata<struct FILE *>: 0x01dc9610
after closing
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am using luajit version LuaJIT 2.0.4 on ubuntu 14.04

Any pointers on how can I debug this segmentation fault will be helpful

Comment: You should use `#filepath+1` in the line `ffi.new("char [?]", #filepath, filepath)` to reserve room for zero terminator.

Comment: FILE API is quite sophisticated, on few platforms have pre-initialisation before main, It can de delicate with dynamic linking

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff .. I was under the assumption that additional room for zero terminator is added by ffi.. or it does not add ??  .. Maybe you are correct, but I did not happen to find any documentation related to this .. :(

Comment: One more thing which is wrong in the program is : strcat(fname,".bin")... Here fname pointer is not allocated enough space to hold the concatenated data.. And according to man page .. https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat .. if destination is not large enough.. program behaviour is unpredictable

Comment: `ffi.new("char[?]", ...)` does add a zero-terminator _if there's enough room._ In your code, there is not, because since you use `#filepath`, you create an array that is only large enough to hold the characters without the terminator.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo  I see.. Thanks for the explanation.. it helps :)